# How Can i cast the Date datatype into integer?(postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want the no of days into a column which is defined as integer in a table i.e.,

`select age('2013-04-06','2013-04-04')` --> gives me `2days` as output

i want that 2 days to be stored into a column with datatype integer..
i tried this but i am getting the no of hours from this query..

`SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (select age('2013-07-06','2013-07-04')))/3600);` --> `48` i.e., 48 hours as `output`

i need the `integer value(2)` from the 2 days or from the 48 hours

How to get this to be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`age(...)` produces an `interval`. You can then use `extract` on the `interval` to get the days:

```
select extract(day from age('2013-04-06','2013-04-04'));
```

With some inputs you'd want to `justify_interval` the `interval` before calling `extract` on it - but `age` produces a pre-justified interval, so that shouldn't be needed in this case.

Comment: Or for dates (not timestamps), just subtract the one from the other. That gives you an integer number of days.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Good point; I tend to forget that, mostly because I rarely use raw `date`.

Comment: `select extract(day from age('2013-07-02','2013-06-01'));` will not work in getting 32 days!! What is the other way to get the days..@craig ringer

Answer (score 2):

```
select '2014-05-02'::date - '2013-04-01'::date;
```

gives the No of days even its difference between day, month or year

Comment: @Craig Ringer  Will this solve the purpose or using this thing ,or it will have any performance changes !

Comment: Simple date subtraction is fine. There is no reason not to do it.  You can subtract from `current_date` if you want a distance from now.